# Get all the documents of a collection which is in a document Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of people (piloto) and each person has a collection with some audios.
I put this audios in a list which send the adapter and show it in a recyclerview.

I have tries with different codes and only this work for me, but the problem is here:

Why the first time that i click an item it show the list of audios empty? Then go back and the next times i click the item it show the list correctly.
It happens when i run the app with my real smarthphone, when i run it with the emulator at the first time it show the list correctly.

```
public class PilotoDetalle extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView rv;

List<Audio> audios;

AdapterAudios adapter;

private Audio audio;

private Piloto piloto;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_piloto_detalle);

    rv = findViewById(R.id.recyclerAudio);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    audios = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new AdapterAudios(audios);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("pilotos").document(piloto.getId()).collection("audios")
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                                    @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.w("TAG", "listen:error", e);
                        return;
                    }

                    for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                        switch (dc.getType()) {
                            case ADDED:
                                Log.d("TAG", "New Msg: " + dc.getDocument().toObject(Message.class));
                                //audios.removeAll(audios);
                                Audio audio = dc.getDocument().toObject(Audio.class);
                                audios.add(audio);
                                break;
                            case MODIFIED:
                                Log.d("TAG", "Modified Msg: " + dc.getDocument().toObject(Message.class));
                                break;
                            case REMOVED:
                                Log.d("TAG", "Removed Msg: " + dc.getDocument().toObject(Message.class));
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the very first time you set the adapter the list is empty.

```
audios = new ArrayList<>();
adapter = new AdapterAudios(audios);
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You should populate your `audios` within the `EventListener` and set/swap the adapter there, to get the data when it is refreshed.